Rails 7 error during application start - Zeitwerk-related errors
I'm upgrading my rails app from 6.1 to 7.0 and i'm running into this runtime error:
I do use the Authlogic gem, but the odd thing is i have no config/initializers file for Authlogic, and i can't find any instance of the constant that it's failing on.
uninitialized constant Patches::AuthlogicPasswordPatch (NameError)
  /myapproot/shared/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/cref.rb:91:in `const_get'
  /myapproot/shared/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/cref.rb:91:in get

UPDATE: After resolving the above issue (see the comment from @alex below for the solution), the next related Zeitwerk issue is:
the next blocker is that Zeitwerk isn't similarly named classes even though they are in different namespaces, which causes this error:
Exception Zeitwerk::NameError in Rack application object 
(expected file app/services/data_tables/base.rb to define 
constant Base, but didn't)

when i enabled logging for Zeitwerk and start the app, i see this:
Zeitwerk@rails.main: file app/services/deployment/models/base.rb is ignored because app/services/data_tables/base.rb has precedence
app/services/deployment/models/base.rb  is defined as:
module Deployment
  module Models
    class Base < ActiveResource::Base
   ...

and  app/services/data_tables/base.rb is:
module DataTables
  class Base
  ...

his is what i have in the config/application.rb:
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services/**/"]
config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/services"


you have a patches/authlogic_password_patch.rb file somewhere in autoload paths which should define Patches::AuthlogicPasswordPatch

Maybe you are hitting this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#autoloading-during-initialization?

@Alex, you were right. it was that file which also had a different class Name that I had to fix, and also add in a Module Patches around the class before that error got resolved.
There are more errors where Zeitwerk is failing on additional class files. Is this something that I can add more details here, or should I close out this post and file a new one? Wasn't sure what SO's guidelines are for this

If the problem is file contents, it's strange that it worked in 6.1 and not in 7.0. Also, strange that the exception is NameError and not Zeitwerk::NameError if this is related to autoloading.

thanks, @Alex. I've updated the question with the additional details

@XavierNoria, I added more details to the question and also clarified that the error does show up as Zeitwerk::NameError
i think Zeitwerk was optional in Rails 6.1, which is probably why this did not happen until i upgraded to Rails 7.0

@weetch I suspect your app may have wildcards in the configuration of autoload_paths. Please, check this section of the migration howto https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#globs-in-config-autoload-paths. If if have not read that guide, I'd recommend it.

@XavierNoria, this is what i have in the config/application.rb:
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services/**/"]

config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"

config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/services"

is this not correct?

@weetch no, it is not. Please read that section of the guide.

i suggest you remove all autoload_paths and just fix your file structure. subdirectories of app are already configured to be in autoload paths. i'm not surprised you have all these issues because of that.

thanks, @XavierNoria . you were right. That fix resolved all the remaining issues. I've posted a summary of the fixes.

Adding a summary of fixes done here in case it helps others. Thanks to @XavierNoria and @Alex for their help.
The initial cause was an outdated patch file for Authlogic that was named in a way that Zeitwerk did not like. I ended up refactoring the code to get rid of the file entirely, but if you have files in lib/patches then you will need to enclose the code inside a Module Patches namespace.
The other issue was that there were a number of classes where Zeitwerk was refusing to autoload classes that were named the same (even though they were clearly inside different namespaces / folder structures). The fix here was to replace this pre-rails-7.0 line in config/application.rb:
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services/**/"]

with:
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services"]

This resolved all the class-name collission issues.

Patches to gems should not be autoloadable/reloadable, because changes in those files won't generally have any effect on the gem. The idiomatic way to have that set up is to tell the autoloader to ignore lib/patches (either Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore("#{Rails.root}/lib/patches"), or pass patches to the ignore list of config.autoload_lib if you have it). Then, on boot require the files as usual. Also, since these files won't be managed by the autoloaders, no conventions are expected on them.
